# Almost sure convergence of series

Tags: calculus, probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I've been trying to prove that the series
$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i
$
converges almost surely. I know that $X_i$ is $Bern(\frac{1}{i^2})$, that $E(Y_i)=0$ and that $E(Y_i^2)=i^2$. Furthermore, all $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent.
I've shown that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(|X_i Y_i|>\varepsilon)<\infty \qquad \sum_{i=1}^\infty E(X_iY_i\mathrm{1}_{(|X_iY_i|\leq\varepsilon)})<\infty
$$
however the last sum, that is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty V(X_iY_i\mathrm{1}_{(|X_iY_i|\leq\varepsilon)})$ in Kolmogorov's three series theorem I cannot crack. Nor can I use Khinchin-Kolmogorovs convergence theorem, since $V(X_iY_i)=1$, so the sum of those alone is clearly divergent.
I am now in need of a hint on how to show that the series converges. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add it.  Everything is basically independent from everything.

Comment: I haven't proven that they are infinite though, and given that this is an assignment from my professor, I highly doubt he's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$, 
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[(X_iY_i)^2 1\{|X_iY_i|\le \epsilon\}]&=\mathsf{E}[(X_iY_i)^2 1\{|X_iY_i|\le \epsilon\}1\{X_i=0\}] \\
&\quad+\mathsf{E}[(X_iY_i)^2 1\{|X_iY_i|\le \epsilon\}1\{X_i=1\}] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[Y_i^2 1\{|Y_i|\le \epsilon\}1\{X_i=1\}] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[Y_i^2 1\{|Y_i|\le \epsilon\}]\,\mathsf{P}(X_i=1)\le (\epsilon/i)^2.
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
\sum_{i\ge 1}\operatorname{Var}(X_iY_i 1\{|X_iY_i|\le \epsilon\})\le \sum_{i\ge 1}(\epsilon/i)^2<\infty.
$$